# In an attempt to install custom rom on my lenovo k6 note ,i have baked up using entire phone using adb backup , how can i restore my phone

Tags: adb, backup, custom-roms, restore

in an attempt to install custom rom i wiped my OS on my lenovo k6 note now its not starting but it is going into twrp recovery mode. is there any way to flash stock rom or any other OS i have tried installing lineage,emulation x, but it failed giving an error .

Comment: ADB backup probably is as best a backup as you can get – but it's by far not complete. Without an OS on the device, it's useless – for that you should have made a [tag:nandroid] backup from TWRP first. Next: your question lacks essential details to help you out of that, like what guide did you follow, and what that error message contains. So if you could **[edit]** your question to include those details, that will help you getting helped. Best luck!

Comment: I guess This would help you. . . . . . . . . . . .. . . . . . . . https://flash-guide.com/download-flash-official-stock-rom-lenovo-k6-note-k53a48/